# getpwuid and getgrgid causes segfault when user does not exist for given UID

Tags: c, uid, file-ownership

I am running a C program in linux, which prints filename plus its user and group ownership. I am using `getpwuid` and `getgrgid`.

When file is owned by non-existent user (ie, there is no entry in `/etc/passwd` for given UID on my machine), my program segfaults with "terminated by signal 11".

How can I make my program behave same as `ls`, so that it prints numerical UID when user does not exist, instead of segfaulting?

Relevant code snippet is below:

```
lstat(filename,&fileStat)

struct group *grp;
struct passwd *pwd;

pwd = getpwuid(fileStat.st_uid);
printf(" %s", pwd->pw_name);

grp = getgrgid(fileStat.st_gid);
printf(" %s", grp->gr_name);
```

Comment: check if pwd is not NULL before accessing it's value. And if the value is NULL you use the uid from lstat as the name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getpwuid` and `getgrgid` return a `NULL` pointer if the user is not found in /etc/passwd database or there was an error.
You have to check that is not `NULL` before accessing it value to avoid segfaults.

You have to also check the return value of `lstat` to be sure that it was successful before using `fileStat` otherwise it cause another segfault. `lstat` returns -1 on fail and sets errno otherwise 0.
[lstat(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/lstat)

```
int ret =  lstat(filename,&fileStat)

if(ret == -1){
  fprintf(stderr, "lstat: (%s): %s\n", filename, strerror(errno));
  return 1;
}

struct group *grp;
struct passwd *pwd;

pwd = getpwuid(fileStat.st_uid);

if(pwd != NULL){
   printf(" %s", pwd->pw_name);
}else{
  printf(" %ld", (long)fileStat.st_uid);
}

grp = getgrgid(fileStat.st_gid);
if(grp != NULL){
 printf(" %s", grp->gr_name);}
else{
  printf(" %ld", (long)fileStat.st_gid);
}
```

[getpwuid(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getpwuid)
Sometimes it might return a NULL pointer on an error and will set `errno`. Which you have to set errno to zero before you check for the specific error

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the man page [GETPWUID(3P)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getpwuid.3p.html#RETURN_VALUE)

> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> The getpwuid() function shall return a pointer to a struct passwd
>          with the structure as defined in  with a matching entry if
>          found. *A null pointer shall be returned if the requested entry is not
>          found*, or an error occurs. On error, errno shall be set to indicate
>          the error.

Check for a null pointer before accessing anything, e.g.

```
pwd = getpwuid(fileStat.st_uid);
if (pwd) {
    printf(" %s", pwd->pw_name);
} else {
    // handle non-existing user entry
}
```